# Assert Failing and I don't know why c++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, assert

from the main.cpp
assert error is here

```
  if(!((CPU1.peek()).isExecuting())) {
                        cout << "Running: " << CPU1.peek().running << endl;
                    (CPU1.peek()).execute();
                        cout << "Running: " << CPU1.peek().running << endl;
                    assert((CPU1.peek()).isExecuting());
                    ((PCB)CPU1.peek()).setStart(slice);
                    ((PCB)CPU1.peek()).setWait(slice-((PCB)CPU1.peek()).getArrival());
                    averageWait1 += ((PCB)CPU1.peek()).getWait();
                    cpu1PCBTotal++;
                    length1 = ((PCB)CPU1.peek()).getLength();
                }



PCB.h
    class PCB
{
private:
    /**
     * this process ID
     */
    int pid;
    /**
     * the nice (priority) value of this process
     */
    int priority;
    /**
     * running status 0=idle 1=running
     */
      int running;
public:
   /**
    * Creates a simulated job with default values for its parameters.
   */

      PCB()
   {
      priority = 19;
      running = 0;
      arrived = 0;
      length = 0;
   }
   PCB(int id, int pval, int run, int arr, int len)
   {
      pid = id;
      priority = pval;
      running = run;
      arrived = arr;
      length = len;
   }
   bool isExecuting() const
   {
      return (running == 1);
   }
   void execute()
   {
      running = 1;
   }

heap.cpp
    template <typename E>
Heap<E>::Heap()
{
   // compiler-generated code .. no need to implement this
}

template <typename E>
Heap<E>::~Heap()
{
   while(tree.size() > 0)
      tree.pop_back();
}

template <typename E>
bool Heap<E>::isEmpty() const
{
   return tree.size() == 0;
}

template<typename E>
void Heap<E>::insert(E item)
{
    tree.push_back(item);
    int place = size()-1;
    int parent = (place-1)/2;
    while(parent >= 0 && tree[place] > tree[parent]) {
        swap(place, parent);
        place = parent;
        parent = (place-1)/2;
    }
}

template<typename E>
E Heap<E>::remove() throw (HeapException)
{
   E root = tree[0];
   tree[0] = tree[size()-1];
   tree.pop_back();
   reheapify(0);
   return root;
}

template<typename E>
const E& Heap<E>::peek() const throw (HeapException)
{
   return tree[0];
}

template<typename E>
int Heap<E>::size()const
{
   return tree.size();
}


template<typename E>
void Heap<E>::swap(int place, int parent)
{
   E temp = tree[place];
   tree[place] = tree[parent];
   tree[parent] = temp;
}

template<typename E>
void Heap<E>::reheapify(int root)
{
        int l = root*2+1;
        int r = root*2+2;
        if(l < size()-1) {
            if(r < size()-1)
                if(tree[root] < tree[r]) {
                    swap(root, r);
                    reheapify(r);
                }
            if(tree[root] < tree[l]) {
                swap(root, l);
                reheapify(l);
            }
        }
}
```

The assertion is failing, and I have no idea why... Please help, thanks
Top is main function, bottom is PCB.h; `CPU` class is a Heap
Originally typecasted CPU1.peek() because it gave me the error "passing 'const PCB' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers" So I guess I needs help calling CPU1.peek().execute()

Comment: And how exactly is it failing? What was the expected and actual result?

Comment: which value do you get from the first and from the second "Running"... `CPU1.peek().running`? And... how is defined `CPU1`?

Comment: CPU1 is defined as Heap CPU1(); and if the if statement resolves true (when CPU1.peek().isRunning() == 0), the next line should make running = 1, which should make the assertion pass

Comment: You have removed the cast to `(PCB)`? Anyway, if `peek()` return a `const` reference to a `PCB`, you can't call a not-const method like `execute()`; if you cast to `(PCB)` the value returned by `peek()` you create (and modify) a temporary object and the `PCB` in the heap remain unmodified. You need a `peek()` that return a not-const reference (or something similar).

Comment: I did it with pointers, sorry I was being dumb